# Erro ao usar rhc

Tags: ruby, openshift

Estou recebendo um erro quando tento usar o `$ rhc setup`, não consigo entender o porque do erro, alguém sabe me dizer o porque do mesmo e como o resolver por gentileza?

a um trecho que diz não ter encontrado o rhc, porém ele esta instalado: `Successfully installed rhc-1.38.4`

```
rhc setup
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:318:in`to_specs': Could not find 'rhc' (>= 0.a) among 103 total gem(s)     (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/dhelbegor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3:/home/dhelbegor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global', execute `gem env` for more information
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:327:in `to_spec'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/rhc:22:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que encontrei foi a seguinte....

```
gem install rubygems-update
pdate_rubygems
gem uninstall rhc
gem install rhc
```

e então finalmente consegui rodar o : `rhc setup`